# Selenium Parallel Tests Queue Handling

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, grid, testng

I have a dynamic list that contains 5k to 10k searching keywords.
The keywords received by api that i built, 
Once I receive a request I launching 5 to 50 browsers parallel (selenium drivers).
All the devices needs to run this list in a website in a round robin or any good way seprate the list between each browser.
The browsers need to will run without  repeating the keywords again.Can anyone assist me please? I am stuck on it for a long time
Thanks

Edit:
This Method starts the total browsers in parallel (The browsers are already up its just reusing)

```
    public void testNGBrowser() {
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setPreserveOrder(true);
    tng.setVerbose(1);

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("Keywork-Search");
    suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.TESTS);
    suite.setThreadCount(DRIVERS.size());
    suite.setVerbose(DRIVERS.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < DRIVERS.size(); i++) {
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        test.setName("KEYWORD" + i);
        test.setGroupByInstances(true);

        classes.add(new XmlClass(SMS.class));
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
    }
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
    suites.add(suite);

    tng.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.TESTS);
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
}
```

This Test are used for all the parallel devices

```
 @Test
    public void VerifyKeyword() {
 System.out.println("VerifyKeyword method, ThreadID: " + 
 Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 10000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
        VerifyPage verifyPage = new VerifyPage(driver);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < KEYWORDS.size(); i++){
                keyword= KEYWORDS.get(KEYWORDS.size() - 1);
                KEYWORDS.remove(keyword);
                verifyPage.verifyKeyword(keyword);
             }
          }
       }
```

I trying always to take the last keyword and then delete the keyword that already run but there is sometimes conflicts that 2 browsers using same keyword

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Then read [ask] and take a few minutes to add some details to your question, especially an [mcve].

Comment: I added a code that may help you to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a class thread specified for your task, and separate the keywords list to keywords chunks for each thread:

```
@Test
public void verifyKeywordTest() {

// Beginning of code here

List<String> keywordsChunks = getChuncks(KEYWORDS);
keywordsChunks.forEach(chunk -> {
    VerifyKeyword verifyKeyword = new VerifyKeyword(getWebDriver(), LOCK, chunk);
    verifyKeyword.start();

// Rest of the code here
```

Runnable class:

```
class VerifyKeyword implements Runnable {

    WebDriver driver;
    VerifyPage verifyPage;
    private Thread thread;
    private List<String> keywords;
    private final Object LOCK;
    private volatile boolean exit = false;


    public VerifyKeyword(
            WebDriver driver, Logger logger, Object LOCK, List<String> keywords) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.LOCK = LOCK;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        VerifyPage verifyPage = new VerifyPage(driver);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++){
                keyword = keywords.get(keywords.size() - 1);
                keywords.remove(keyword);
                verifyPage.verifyKeyword(keyword);
             }
          }     
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            LOCK.notify();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this, this.getClass().getName());
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        exit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

already did my friend.

Comment: As the asker you can also mark the question as solved (green v sign)

Comment: @BrandonJThompson please see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 1.vote it 2. Accept it

Answer (score 0):

if you want unique keyword all the time,

add time millies in your random keyword.

```
String ranKeyword = "jayanth";
long rn = new Date().getTime();
String newRanKey = ranKeyword+"_"+rn;
```

Always use date as your first choice to get unique keyword.